# PartPainted in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, function, procedure

What is the equivalent procedure or function or code of PartPainted (c#) in vb.net? Here is a sample snippet of the code in c# but when I convert it to vb.net code, the PartPainted is not known function.

```
if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The looks eerily similar to the code from the sample [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article:

```
// If the cell is in editing mode, there is nothing else to paint
if (!cellEdited)
{
    if (PartPainted(paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground))
    {
        // Paint a NumericUpDown control
        // Take the borders into account
```

If that's so, it's not a framework/built in function - it's just another method in the same class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Little utility function called by the Paint function to see if a particular part needs to be painted. 
/// </summary>
private static bool PartPainted(DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts, DataGridViewPaintParts paintPart)
{
    return (paintParts & paintPart) != 0;
}
```

Which should be trivial to convert to VB.